# Cant access throug url lazy load modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, router, production-environment

I have a problem with the routes after doing "ng build --prod"

I have configured to modules to be lazy loading in my project. They load with no problem if i access them with a link like this:

```
<a classs="waves-effect btn" [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
```

But if i try to input the URL into the browser i get a 404 error.

This is my main router:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: './components/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: './components/auth/auth.module#AuthModule' }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404'
  }
];
```

Is there a router missing configuration ?
Or what is the problem ?

Please help.

Comment: Does it behave the same way with ng serve?

Comment: @hogan No, only stops working when i do the production build.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test here right now but I assume it has to do with

- either a missing `<base href="/">` tag in the index.html
- or the path inside your loadChildren needs to be 'app/components/...' instead of './components/...' (according to the angular routed docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: im going to try this too

Comment: i cant set 'app/components' because the main router in under app. So if i make that change i get an error. Dont know what i have to put in the base tag. give me an example please.

Comment: base tag should be just as above mentioned, nothing else. What do you mean by `i cant set 'app/components' because the main router in under app`? you should import the main router into the app module and configure your lazy routes there. Here is the correct example : `https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration`

Answer (score 0):

i guess im not familiar with your pattern.  but maybe it's an auth thing..  where you have 2 entries for path: ''

but maybe you just need to set a path: 'login'  ?

Comment: Already tried that but still do not work when i input the url

Comment: here is a working example that I am using: const appRoutes: Routes = [
 // Dashboard
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/Dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'Dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/_dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
 
 // MapView
 { path: 'mapview', redirectTo: '/MapView', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'MapView', loadChildren: './mapview/_mapview.module#MapViewModule' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRouting { }

Comment: Why do you export the router module? @Jesse

Comment: also maybe try this:  [RouterLink]="'/login'"

Comment: it looks like that export allows me to add <router-outlet></router-outlet> to the app's template

Comment: it's also case sensitive, so if you have path: 'login' make sure that you use all lower in the url, hence my redirectTo's in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

may be angular is confused with this router configuration

```
{ path: '', loadChildren: './components/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
{ path: '', loadChildren: './components/auth/auth.module#AuthModule' }
```

did you tried with giving some path to modules

Comment: Let me test this

Comment: Tried this and still the same problem